# Rails: path-string changed automatically in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I found this weird-looking bug in my app. I call user avatar as a background image like this:

```
<span class="user-image" style="background-image:url(<%= avatar_tiny(current_user) %>);"></span>
```

avatar_tiny is a helper which should returns a path to user's avatar or a path to the default image:

```
def avatar_tiny(user)
    if user.contact.avatar?
      user.contact.avatar.url(:tiny)
    else
     'assets/avatar_default_tiny.png'
    end
  end
```

It works correct on the home page. But when I go to the any subpage Rails somehow change automatically this path adding it's name to this string. E.g. "/profile/assets/avatar_default_tiny.png

And I get this error in my rails console:

```
Started GET "/profile/assets/avatar_default_tiny.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-10 05:32:51 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/profile/assets/avatar_default_tiny.png"):
```

Why this is happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `asset_path` helper to get the relative location of your default image. Change your helper's else statement to `asset_path('avatar_default_tiny.png')`